# What is an idiomatic way to have multiple structs with the same properties in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust, properties

I'm aware that Rust does not have inheritance and that the language provides and easy way to share different implementations of the same methods across objects through the use of Traits. But is there an idiomatic way to share property name definitions or do they need to be defined on each struct?

My use case is that I have many different structs that track some information. Each piece of information can be updated and I want each struct to know the date of its last update. Is there a common pattern (maybe macros?) to add a `last_update` property to all the structs or must I add it to each struct explicitly?

Comment: Your example is very basic so my answer is basic, yes.

Comment: There are many options, and the details depend on the specifics. If you just want a `last_updated` field on each struct, your best option is to simply add it. If you want to have some additional functionality available on each struct, there are many ways to achieve that, and we'd need to know more about your requirements. Do these really need to be structs, or will some higher-level abstraction, e.g. based on a hash map mapping field names to values, work as well?

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not possible to automatically update a `last_updated` field whenever you change the value of a different field in a regular struct, in case this is what you want. Field assignments can't trigger any custom behaviour in Rust.

Comment: Inspired by @Sven's comment I wrote [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b31b5463ea08109718e321f6cebf1807) to demonstrate using a decorator struct to provide this behavior with an `update` method that takes a closure. When you want to add behavior to a type, implementing a trait is one way, but wrapping it in another type allows you to also add data (like a timestamp field) at the same time.

Comment: @trentcl I like how this moves the old value into the closure to achieve encapsulation – there's not way to leak a mutable reference from the closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this via traits, the closest thing is the "Fields in Traits" RFC ([discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/fields-in-traits/6933), [RFC](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/fields-in-traits-rfc/blob/master/0000-fields-in-traits.md)), but that doesn't seem terribly active as of now.

The simplest way to do this is to have a type / struct with a method and include that field in any struct you want:

```rust
struct UpdateTimestamp {
    timestamp: Timestamp, // dummy type
}

impl UpdateTimestamp {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.timestamp = now(); // dummy function
    }
    fn last_updated(&self) -> Timestamp {
        self.timestamp
    }
}
```

You could then include this in any struct where you want the functionality:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    my_field: u32,
    my_other_field: i32,
    update_ts: UpdateTimestamp,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn my_field(&self) -> u32 {
        // Getter - no update
        self.my_field
    }
    fn set_my_field(&mut self, my_field: u32) {
        self.update_ts.update();
        self.my_field = my_field;
    }
    fn last_updated(&self) -> Timestamp {
        self.update_ts.last_updated()
    }
}
```

Now you *could* write a complicated macro for this which automates the implementation part (injects updates into the setters and the `last_updated` method in the impl block), but unless you're doing this *a lot* I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: I would prefer https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3305574e02a069254596bf1441e5953

Comment: Yes, good point, will in the future. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

I'm late for the party, but I came up with [boilermates](https://crates.io/crates/boilermates) just for this reason. It's a proc macro that allows you to generate multiple structs that share some of their fields, easily convert between them, and create common function implementations for them.

Very much a work in progress, but it works in more than a few basic cases I've tried it with.